# Prevent Duplicate Table entry in Database

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates, create-table

I'm trying to Create new table for record of each company and its information. And for that I'm using simple Create query. Is there any way to prevent duplication of Table?

Answer (score 3):

In every database that I know of, duplicate table names are not allowed.  In some, there is a third element, the schema, but I assume everything is in the same schema.

In other words, trying to create a duplicate will cause an error.  Try it.

By the way, you should always tag your questions with the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your brief suggestion. Yes, It is prevent me to enter duplicate table. so its good. And about tag, I'll take care of it next time for sure. Thanks.